# C# While (i++ ...) when increments?

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, post-increment

Why does While loop post-increments (or post-decrements) a variable right after examination of the condition and not after the whole loop?

As in:

```
int x = 0;
while (x++ < 5)
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

The output is: 1 2 3 4 5, when I believe it should be 0 1 2 3 4. It seems it checks the condition - true - inrements right away. Is that normal behaviour, becase I've recently been practising Plain C and it's completely different.

Should I rather go with this option for more clarity?

```
while (x < 5)
Console.WriteLine(x);
++x;
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator

Comment: You really should be using braces here.

Comment: Because that's how it works. It's the same in C.

Comment: and rather a for loop for such a well defined limit

Comment: You're incrementing `x` before you write the line.. What do you expect?

Comment: if you want to test and increment at the end then use `do, while`

Comment: file a bug on your c compiler - its wrong

Comment: The pre- and post- increments are done in one operation, and have nothing to do with a loop. In the `while` condition, `x++` returns the current value of `x` (`0` in the first iteration) and increments the value. In the next line, `x` has been incremented, so you see `1` output to the console.

Comment: Your second code snippet is an endless loop!

Answer (score 8):

If you would use a for loop your expected answer would be correct:
the while does not have any special inner workings like that.

```
for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
```

is the way to write this with the most clarity.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is correct and ANSI-C does it in the same way, if you execute the same code.
`x++` is "one command" and the increment is already done as soon as you move on to the next command.
The difference between `x++` and `++x` is, that the later one returns the "new value" and the first one returns the "old value".
May the following be what you want:

```
int x = 0;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine(x++);
}
while (x < 5);
```

But I also think in general this specific case of "do it 5-times" is best solved with a `for`-loop as suggested by @ikdekker.

Answer (score 2):

Your loop is equivalent to:

```
int x = 0;
while (x < 5)
{
  x++;
  Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Since the incrementation will be done immeditely after the condition line (x<5).

So your second loop is the correct one (you should add braces though), or if you really want condition and increment in the same time you can use the do..while loop:

```
int x = 0;
do
{
  Console.WriteLine(x);
} while (++x < 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop for this as has been mentioned. You can also declare the x variable inside the for loop.

```
for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using `x++` in the wrong place

```
Console.WriteLine(x++)
```

instead of

```
while(x++ < 5)
```

mark as answer if it helps